# Paste two ranges from two different workbooks into an Outlook mail body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, range

I have to paste two selected ranges, from two different workbooks into a mail body.

The first workbook is the parent workbook where the macro is located. We select a range from there, the second workbook is opened via the macro and a range is selected.

Both the ranges are to be pasted in Outlook mail body.

I tried the below macro along with the rangetohtml function.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
' You need to use this module with the RangetoHTML subroutine.
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set Parent_wkb = ThisWorkbook
    cnt_row = Parent_wkb.Worksheets("1Summary - All").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cnt_col = Parent_wkb.Worksheets("1Summary - All").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    l1 = cnt_row + 7
    last_box = cnt_col - 2
    last_box_Ltr = Evaluate("substitute(address(1, " & last_box & ", 4), ""1"", """")")

    r1 = "B2:" & last_box_Ltr & l1

    hide1 = cnt_col - 10
    hide1_cell = Evaluate("substitute(address(1, " & hide1 & ", 4), ""1"", """")")
    hide2 = cnt_col - 11
    hide2_cell = Evaluate("substitute(address(1, " & hide2 & ", 4), ""1"", """")")

     Worksheets("1Summary - All").Columns(hide2_cell & ":" & hide1_cell).Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    Set rng = Worksheets("1Summary - All").Range(r1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ' You can also use a range with the following statement.
    ' Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng_dt = Worksheets("1Summary - All").Range("AGQ2")
    dt = rng_dt.Cells(1, 1).Value
    dt_formatted1 = Format(dt, "dd-MMMM-yyyy")
    dt_formatted2 = Format(dt, "dd MMMM yyyy")
    ' folder = Mid(dt, 2, 4)            

    'open the global variable file to get the acu file name along with the file name to be attached 

    'Attach_xcl - an excel workbook to be attached (working fine)
    'body_xcl - another excel workbook, from where I have to select the range
    'both the workbook names along with their path are stored in this global variable file(working fine)

    Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\vfpnbrgspr0\LESR_Phase2_R_RPA\Sayan\Global_Variable_Singapore.xlsx")
    Set rng_xcl1 = wkb1.Worksheets("Global_Variable").Range("B17")
    Attach_xcl = rng_xcl1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Set rng_xcl2 = wkb1.Worksheets("Global_Variable").Range("B18")
    Body_xcl = rng_xcl2.Cells(1, 1).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'open the acu limit(Body_xcl) file for second table for mail body
    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Body_xcl)

    Set rng2 = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    Set rng2 = wkb2.Worksheets("Biz Breakdown").Range("body").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ' You can also use a range with the following statement.
    ' Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        wkb2.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    wkb2.Close

    '------------------------------PREPARE THE MAIL TO BE SENT---------------------------------------------'
    Dim StrBody1 As String
    ' Build the string that you want to add.
    StrBody1 = "Dear All," & "<br><br>" & _
               "This is confidential." & "<br><br><br>"

    Dim StrBody2 As String
    ' Build the string that you want to add.
    StrBody2 = " " & "<br><br><br><br>" & _
               "Thanks," & "<br>" & _
               "user" & "<br>"

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
       ' .To = "xxxx"
        .To = "xxxx"
        .CC = "xxxx"
        .BCC = "xxxx"
        .Subject = "This is confidential" & dt_formatted2

  'THE LINE BELOW IS NOT WORKING, IF I WORK WITH 'rng' ITS WORKING FINE, WHEN I ADD THE SECOND 'rng2' THE BODY OF THE MAIL IS BLANK

        .HTMLBody = StrBody1 & RangetoHTML(rng) & " " & RangetoHTML(rng2) & StrBody2
        '.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng2) & StrBody2
        .Attachments.Add (Attach_xcl)
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the e-mail message.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    Worksheets("1Summary - All").Columns(hide2_cell & ":" & hide2_cell).Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("1Summary - All").Columns(hide1_cell & ":" & hide1_cell).Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Publish the sheet to an .htm file.
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    ' Read all data from the .htm file into the RangetoHTML subroutine.
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    ' Close TempWB.
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Delete the htm file.
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having comes from the fact that you close `wkb2` before you convert `rng2` to html. When you get to the `RangetoHTML(rng2)` line, `rng2` is no longer available, if `wkb2` is closed.

So you should convert `rng2` to html and store it in a variable before you close `wkb2`. 
You could do something like this:

```
    If rng2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        wkb2.Close
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim HtmlRng2 as string
        HtmlRng2 = RangeToHtml(rng2)
    End If
```

And you would change

```
.HTMLBody = StrBody1 & RangetoHTML(rng) & " " & RangetoHTML(rng2) & StrBody2
```

to

```
.HTMLBody = StrBody1 & RangetoHTML(rng) & " " & HtmlRng2 & StrBody2
```

Otherwise you would have to keep `wkb2` open until after you've filled your email `htmlbody` with the ranges.